# DevDemon Updater - updating EE2.5.2 to 2.6.1 Error Unexpected server response, probably a php error

Tags: update, devdemon, devdemon-updater

I am trying to update my EE installation from 2.5.2 to 2.6.1 using DevDemon Updater v3.2.5.

I get the following errors on the "update CP Theme Corporate (N/A)" stage (first stage)

"Error Unexpected server response, probably a php error. Show more"

When I view the PHP errors, they all relate to images in a themes/cp_global_images/corporate/
folder, which does not exist, I have looked in other EE installations and that folder doesn't exist in them either.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:
copy(/x/x/public_html/themes/cp_global_images/**corporate**/calendar.gi
f)
[function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/updater_transfer.php

Line Number: 820

Screen grab here: [image: Screen grab here]

Comment: it also fails when it tries to update the default theme

Comment: I have a similar and unresolved error in that same update.  I hope someone can help you here!